# Is it okay to whistle after Maghrib?

Tags: sunnah

I have been told once that it is not good to whistle after Maghrib because it attracts the Shayateen/bad jinn to you.  Are there any hadiths on this?

Comment: +1 Thanks for reminding me of my grandmother who used to scare us so we don't go out after Maghrib... I guess it is an Arabian superstition..

Comment: Whistling is considered as bad thing in Islam (at any time). Doing a bad thing during maghrib (or any prayer) is a worse thing. Between a `worse` thing and a `bad` thing the bad one is preffered. But it is still a `bad` thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seriously doubt if there is a hadith like that. Because whistling in general is considered a bad manner. It is linguistically called: Al-Muka' which is one of pre-Islamic customs and is considered a bad manner. According to some [scholars](http://www.alifta.com/Fatawa/FatawaChapters.aspx?View=Page&PageID=10428&PageNo=1&BookID=7), whistling is not even permissible generally.

> Their Salât (prayer) at the House (of Allâh, i.e. the Ka‘bah at
>   Makkah) was nothing but whistling and clapping of hands.

Surah Al-Anfal (8:35)

It doesn't answer your question but just a food for thought.

Comment: agree with Ershad. after Maghrib seems to be superstition. Quran generally consider it bad.

Comment: I think there's a hadith about don't let your kids out around Maghrib time because that's when shayateen are active. That may play into it thoguh.